# Traffic Light Changing Colors based on JButton

Tags: java, computer-science

I am new to stack overflow so I do not know how everything works yet, just a little by the way. With that out the way, I know what I have wrong here and it's definitely the paint components, but how can I change it so that my ActionListener can complete the commands I had given it. What I am trying to say is if the JButton is clicked once, then a stop light area- dimensions in the code- will light up with a certain color, and it press again and again, the light will move on to the next color and so on. Here is what I have for that specific side that I need help with.

```js
package trafficlight;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class TrafficMethods extends JPanel
{
    private JButton c;
    private final int x=50, y=50, xx=100, yy=260, d=60;
    private int count;
    public TrafficMethods()
    {
        c = new JButton("Change the color");
        c.addActionListener(new ActC());
        add(c);
    }
    private class ActC implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics p)
            {
                count++;
                switch(count)
                {
                    case '1':
                        p.setColor(Color.red);
                        p.fillOval(x+20, y+20, d, d);
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        p.setColor(Color.green);
                        p.fillOval(x+20, y+100, d, d);
                        break;
                    case'3':
                        p.setColor(Color.yellow);
                        p.fillOval(x+20, y+180, d, d);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***** EDIT *****
I made an entirely new class code and I was wondering if I could get this to work. Everything works fine, just when I click the button that says "Change the color" nothing will happen. What can I change in my code so that every time I click "Change the color" it actually will do that?

```js
package trafficlight;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TrafficPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    
    private int clicks;
    private final int x=50, y=50, xx=100, yy=260, d=60;
    private Button color;
    private JPanel panel;
    private boolean redclick = false, yellowclick = false, greenclick = false;
    
    public TrafficPanel()
    {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,400));
        panel = new JPanel();
        
        color = new Button ("Change the color");
        
        panel.add(color);
        
        add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        color.addActionListener(this);
    }
    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        setBackground(Color.blue);
        
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(x, y, xx, yy);
        
        if(redclick == true)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(x+20, y+20, d, d);
            redclick = false;
        }
        if(yellowclick == true)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.yellow);
            g.fillOval(x+20, y+100, d, d);
            yellowclick = false;
        }
        if(greenclick == true)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillOval(x+20, y+180, d, d);
            greenclick = false;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        clicks++;
        switch (clicks)
        {
            case '1':
                greenclick = true;
                repaint();
            case '2':
                yellowclick = true;
                repaint();
            case '3':
                redclick = true;
                repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should first remove the javascript tag from your question and add java tag .

Comment: `paintComponent` shouldn't be in your `ActionListener` class, but rather your `JPanel` class.  As a general rule, actions and rendering (painting) should be kept separate when designing UIs.

Comment: I edited my code to follow what you said Joe but I am still getting no changing lights on my traffic light. The body of the light is there but not the red/green/yellow lights.